# Global Variable not updating from request get function

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, request

I would like to set a global variable and set it value from inside of node.js ***request*** module get function. Here is my code -

```
var req = require('request');
var server = '';

req.get('http://httpbin.org/headers',function(err,res,body){
server = res.headers.server;
console.log(body);
});

console.log(server); // result undefined
```

Problem is everytime I get undefined.

Comment: Yes, inside get function , console.log(server) and console.log(res.headers.server) are working !

Comment: The problem with your code is that you print the `server` immediately, but the callback function will be called only when the request is finished which could be miliseconds or even seconds after you print your variable. What do you want to achieve? You should show some more code.

Comment: Hi @vsakos , I am studying nodejs request package to learn How can I get any value from response header or cookies and then push into a global variable to use with another request.

Comment: That's not how it works. Node is async, which means when you run an async function, it returns immediately, doesn't wait for the callback function to be called. If you want to use the data you get from one request right after it finishes, you can either start another request from the callback of the first one or use promises to avoid the _callback hell_.

Answer (score -1):

It's not recommended you set global in a callback.
It's better you use events for this

**EDIT**

```
app.on('serverHeader', function(data){
//do stuff
});

app.get('...', function(req, res, cb){
app.emit('serverHeader', res.headers);
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you help me to set that using events? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand who and why vote me down!!!

Comment: The code in the question is asking how making a request with the request module. Your code shows how to *receive* a request with a completely different module (which looks like Express).

Comment: @Quentin ok my bad. I mistake. So you or anybody can make me clear, not vote down. Also the code is assumed as pesudo code, so it gives idea how do events in nodejs